# Replace all values In Pandas data frame with only the integer at the end of current string

Tags: pandas

Current data frame:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | School_09 |
| John | School_23 |

How I want it:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | 09 |
| John | 23 |

Answer (score 1):

We can also try using `str.replace` here:

```py
df["ID"] = df["ID"].str.replace(r'.*_', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with the `\d+$` regex (one or more trailing digits) to collect only the trailing digits:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$')
```

output:

```
          ID
  Name      
0 Peter   09
1 John    23
```

and to have a numeric type, combine with [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$', expand=False), errors='coerce')
```

output:

```
    Name  ID
0  Peter   9
1   John  23
```